# Base amount of star rating before values applied

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have a rating system in place that is working fine

#### customers_helper.rb

```
module CustomersHelper
  def show_stars(review)
    @star = raw('<li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></li>') * (review.rating)
    @star.html_safe
  end
end
```

#### reviews.haml

```
%table.table.
  %thead
    %tr
      %th{ :style => "width:9%" } Ratings
      %tbody
        - @reviews.each do |review|
          %tr
            %td
              %ul.list-inline.rating=show_stars(review)
```

All this is doing is taking a integer value 1-5 and renders that many stars accordingly.

How would i go about always rendering 5 stars and adding a class to the exsisting stars based on the database value?

Answer (score 0):

This is a way I did this recently, not so clean(IMHO), but it works fine:

```
def total_stars
    5   
end

def show_stars(num_star)
    buffer = ""
    total_stars.times do |i|
        buffer << "<i #{ 'class=\'starred\'' if i < current_stars }>*</i>"  
    end
    buffer
end

show_stars(review.rating)
```

Comment: Does this go in the helper? I seem to be running into errors if i place it there

Comment: the methods would be in the helper, but the call to `show_stars(review.rating)` would be in your haml view